# Как из потока (Thread) корректно читать состояния визуальных компонентов главной формы?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

Допустим из потока с циклом необходимо проверять состояние `CheckBox` который находится на главной форме. Будет ли корректна нижеследующая реализация, через булевую глобальную переменную, чтение и запись которой, происходят внутри критической секции. На сколько это правильно? Заранее спасибо за советы.

Упрощенно код выглядит так:

```
var
  vChecked: boolean;

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
  while True do
    begin
      Sleep(2000);
      CriticalSection.Enter;
      case vChecked of
        True: ShowMessage('checked');
        False: ShowMessage('unchecked');
      end;
      CriticalSection.Leave;

      if Terminated then break;
    end;
end;

procedure TForm1.CheckBox1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CriticalSection.Enter;
  vChecked := CheckBox1.Checked;
  CriticalSection.Leave;
end;
```

Comment: чем вас не устраивает стандартное взаимодействие с главным потоком через synchronize? Использование глобальных переменных - не есть хорошо. Хоть и для примера (видимо) но использовать showMessage в потоке, тоже не корректно. Для чтения данных в потоке КС вам не нужна, в принципе, вы же не изменяете данные, а только читаете.  Необходимости в КС в главном потоке тоже нет, ибо судя по вашему коду, это единственный поток который изменяет значение. Но и в принципе, изменение булевой переменной, это вроде как атомарная операция.

Comment: Резюмируя, для описанной задачи КС не нужны в принципе, а чтение свойств формы делайте через synchronize.

Comment: Плюс к тому, что описано выше, можно использовать `SendMessage` или `PostMessage`. Если нужны примеры - обращайтесь, хотя в инете таких примеров пруд пруди.

Comment: Synchronize тут тоже излишен опять-таки из-за булевой переменной. Значение переменной выставляется в главном потоке (абсолютно правильно - именно там, где меняется чекбокс!), во вторичном - только считывается. Никакого смысла в синхронизации этих действий нет. Вполне нормальный код, действительно выкинуть критическую секцию, вместо глобальной переменной - сделать поле потоку и вместо ShowMessage использовать MessageBox.

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста - при чем здесь SendMessage? Значение из главного потока нужно передать во вторичный. Вы предлагаете для такого простого действия реализовывать цикл выборки сообщений в дополнительном потоке?

Comment: Вообще то, что Вы делаете противоречит модели Model- View-Control. то есть то что пишется в GUI должен быть считано классом и хранится в объекте классе, а потом уже данные нужно брать из этого объекта. GUI объекты должны быть максимально отделены от управляющего кода. Это делает его более портабельным и независимым от используемых компонентов.

Comment: Согласен, передавать значения из основного потока через сообщения не совсем корректно. У меня почему-то сложилось стойкое ощущение того, что нужно сделать наоборот:)

Comment: @kami synchronize тут предлагался для считывания свойства формы, а не булевой переменной. В общем случае все взаимодействие с VCL должно происходить через главный поток, в данном частном случае можно и без этого

Comment: Сообщения нельзя передать в поток, так как там скорее всего нет визуального компонента с Handle